# Call Rest API and handle response in existing Azure Logic App Flow

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an existing Azure Logic App Flow, on a condition I want to call an API and want to return the response.
Note- not just have to call API, but handle the response and send it as a response from Logic App
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us what were you able to achieve? Are you facing any issue in particular step?

Comment: @Mandar I am using Http Request Trigger which is an entry point, I pass the JSON object to this endpoint, later in the flow on the basis of Condition, I am using Http Request action which give options to configure URL and HTTP Verbs and pass object to API, but there is no way I see to handle the response

Comment: You mean the response from the API or the response that you want to send out of the Logic App?

Comment: Hi BreakHead, could you please provide some screenshots to further clarify your question ？

Comment: @Mandar I want to send the response I get from API as a response from my Logic app

Comment: @HuryShen I have added Screen Shots

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, added Parse Json to parse response from request action
[image]